# url which references an object

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, url, linq-to-xml

I'm currently trying to implement this [Silverlight Timeline](http://timeline.codeplex.com/) into an application. The problem is that if you want to fill this timeline you need to refer a XML file via url:

```
<timeline:TimelineTray.Urls>
    <timeline:UriInfo Url="http://localhost:4444/Monet.xml" />
</timeline:TimelineTray.Urls>
```

But the elements which are shown on the timeline aren't static. So there are several pages where we're gonna use this timeline. On runtime we generate new, edit and delete items. So I had to generate a dynamic XML "document" via the XDocument class (Silverlight). That worked fine but then I saw that you have to reference this XML document via url:

> **Urls**
>
> ';' delimited list of data xmls with events to show. You need to
>   specify this parameter or timeline will appear blank.

So well, how can I solve that problem? The way to just bind the XDocument from the ViewModel to the TimeLine won't work. I don't want to save this generated XDocument just to be able to reference it. Is there another way?

***edit:**
I found another solution. It's through codebehind, though:*

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    // stuff you'd like to get
);
timeLine.ResetEvents(doc);
```

There's also a way to generate events without generating an XDocument.

I'd still like any answers if somebody gets a better idea which doesn't need a codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the TimeLine control doesn't support binding to an XDocument, and you want your XDocument to be in your ViewModel, you can implement your own PropertyChanged handler in the View's codebehind to refresh the timeline, e.g.

```
var myVM = this.DataContext as MyViewModelType;
if (myVM != null)
{
    myVM.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "MyXDocumentProperty")
            {
                this.timeLine.ResetEvents(myVM.MyXDocumentProperty);
            }
        };
}
```

Then when your VM sets the MyXDocumentProperty property, PropertyChanged will fire and the timeline will get refreshed.